# Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I am building a app by Flutter.
I have got this error message when doing "pod install" and the pod install failed and stopped.

The error message:

> [!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

> The Swift pod `DKPhotoGallery` depends upon `SDWebImage` and `SDWebImageFLPlugin`, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

Where should I set "use_modular_headers!" in the Podfile? thanks!

Answer (score 33):

I tried out the solution. "use_frameworks!" should be added here in 'ios/Podfile':

```
.
.
.
target 'Runner' do
      # Flutter Pod
    
      use_frameworks! #add here
    
      copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
      copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
      copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 13):

With cocoapods 1.9 a new command is shipped
`use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` which allows static linking

Answer (score 6):

those seem are not define modules.
in your Podfile add:

```
pod 'YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME', :modular_headers => true
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this in the Pod file before the `target`

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but none of the solutions worked for me.

```
 target 'Runner' do use_frameworks! use_modular_headers!

 flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
 pod 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery', :git => 'https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git', :modular_headers => true //this is the library i was getting error.
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the contents of this path resolved the issue for local env:

> `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/`

In this case, it had folder `/12.5.7 (16H81)` , where as current Xcode is now at 14.1

Thanks to:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/53202

Answer (score 0):

add **use_modular_headers!** and **use_frameworks!** in pod file after target

Answer (score -1):

add `use_modular_headers!` in pod file after target

```
target 'KF6Mobile' do
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
    ....
```

reference:https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.5.0/

Comment: In your answer, please explain why this works, perhaps even cite a reference.

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful. Please edit your answer and add some details about what this code does and why it fixes OP's problem.

Comment: please read it https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.5.0/

Comment: Read, the Altering CocoaPods to use frameworks:
https://rnfirebase.io/#altering-cocoapods-to-use-frameworks

 @JeffC